# Avoid long lines in Perl scripts

Tags: perl, coding-style

I have used `\` at the end of shell scripts to avoid long lines, and improve code readability.
But I cannot do it in Perl, what am I doing wrong ? Do I have to escape them in any way?

I mean something like:

```
my $dbh = DBI->connect("DBI:mysql:database=xxxxxxx;host=xxxxxt", "xxxx", "xxxxxx", \%dbattr) or die ("Bla bla bla bla");
```

Answer (score 16):

Perl statements are <strike>terminated</strike> separated by a semicolon `;`, you don't need to write code on one line. Your example can be formatted as:

```
my $dbh = DBI->connect(
  "DBI:mysql:database=xxxxxxx;host=xxxxxt",
  "xxxx",
  "xxxxxx",
  \%dbattr
) or
  die ("Bla bla bla bla");
```

Or in any way you like.

You can also take a look at tools like [perltidy](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Perl%3a%3aTidy) to automatically beautify your code.

Comment: minor nit, `;` separates statements, it does not terminate them.  the semicolon is not needed after each statement unless there is a following statement.

Answer (score 7):

There is no need to escape.

From [perldoc perlsyn](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlsyn.html):

> Perl is a free-form language, you can format and indent it however you
>   like. Whitespace mostly serves to separate tokens, unlike languages
>   like Python where it is an important part of the syntax:

```
my $dbh = 
 DBI->connect("DBI:mysql:database=xxxxxxx;host=xxxxxt", 
 "xxxx", "xxxxxx", \%dbattr
 ) 
 or die ("Bla bla bla bla");
```

Comment: "Whitespace is allowed" - this is one of the biggest reasons why I will always prefer Perl over Python.